# I am trying to use overflow property but it isnt work as expected

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am trying to use overflow, but its not allowing me to scroll but it works as I need that popup on hover, is there any way so I can use overflow visible as well as scroll.

I tried position fixed too, for the span element inside `server__list` but it doesn't seems to work as well, rest of the elements going underneath, Is there any other property or a better way for doing this?

Here is my code

```css
:root{
    --blurple-color: #7289DA;
    --lighter-color: #32363a;
    --light-color: #2C2F33;
    --white-color: #ffffff;
    --dark-color: #23272A;
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Balsamiq+Sans&display=swap');

body, html{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

*{
    font-family: 'Balsamiq Sans', cursive;
}

body{
    background-color: var(--lighter-color);
}

.server__list{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: var(--dark-color);
    width: 50px;
    overflow-x: visible;
}

.server__list::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.channel__list{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--light-color);
}

.user__container{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #26292c;
}

.user__container .profile{
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px;
}

.user__container .profile img{
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.user .user__name{
    color: var(--white-color);
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}

.user .user__discrim{
    color: grey;
    font-size: 8px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}

.profile #logout{
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: rgb(187, 55, 3);
    margin-left: 40px;
    transition: color;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.profile #logout:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: darkred;
}

/* Showing Servers */
.server__list .server{
    margin: 10px;
}


.server__list .server img{
    width: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.server:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.server span{
    display: none;
    background-color: #0f1011;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}

.server:hover > span{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -40px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Web</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="./static/assets/icon.png" id="header__icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1144a6771a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="server__list">
        <div class="server">
            <img src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/3eMPIDjl49YlAuYjS-x42t4ZvBwDJZhq84zKoHNAVls/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/347724952100667394/a_a76024fba4dbe97464128190a5b8cc91.gif?width=300&height=300"
                alt="">
            <span>Server Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="server">
            <img src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/3eMPIDjl49YlAuYjS-x42t4ZvBwDJZhq84zKoHNAVls/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/347724952100667394/a_a76024fba4dbe97464128190a5b8cc91.gif?width=300&height=300"
                alt="">
            <span>Server Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="server">
            <img src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/3eMPIDjl49YlAuYjS-x42t4ZvBwDJZhq84zKoHNAVls/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/347724952100667394/a_a76024fba4dbe97464128190a5b8cc91.gif?width=300&height=300"
                alt="">
            <span>Server Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="server">
            <img src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/3eMPIDjl49YlAuYjS-x42t4ZvBwDJZhq84zKoHNAVls/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/347724952100667394/a_a76024fba4dbe97464128190a5b8cc91.gif?width=300&height=300"
                alt="">
            <span>Server Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="server">
            <img src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/3eMPIDjl49YlAuYjS-x42t4ZvBwDJZhq84zKoHNAVls/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/347724952100667394/a_a76024fba4dbe97464128190a5b8cc91.gif?width=300&height=300"
                alt="">
            <span>Server Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="server">
            <img src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/3eMPIDjl49YlAuYjS-x42t4ZvBwDJZhq84zKoHNAVls/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/347724952100667394/a_a76024fba4dbe97464128190a5b8cc91.gif?width=300&height=300"
                alt="">
            <span>Server Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="server">
            <img src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/3eMPIDjl49YlAuYjS-x42t4ZvBwDJZhq84zKoHNAVls/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/347724952100667394/a_a76024fba4dbe97464128190a5b8cc91.gif?width=300&height=300"
                alt="">
            <span>Server Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="server">
            <img src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/3eMPIDjl49YlAuYjS-x42t4ZvBwDJZhq84zKoHNAVls/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/347724952100667394/a_a76024fba4dbe97464128190a5b8cc91.gif?width=300&height=300"
                alt="">
            <span>Server Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="server">
            <img src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/3eMPIDjl49YlAuYjS-x42t4ZvBwDJZhq84zKoHNAVls/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/347724952100667394/a_a76024fba4dbe97464128190a5b8cc91.gif?width=300&height=300"
                alt="">
            <span>Server Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="server">
            <img src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/3eMPIDjl49YlAuYjS-x42t4ZvBwDJZhq84zKoHNAVls/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/347724952100667394/a_a76024fba4dbe97464128190a5b8cc91.gif?width=300&height=300"
                alt="">
            <span>Server Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="server">
            <img src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/3eMPIDjl49YlAuYjS-x42t4ZvBwDJZhq84zKoHNAVls/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/347724952100667394/a_a76024fba4dbe97464128190a5b8cc91.gif?width=300&height=300"
                alt="">
            <span>Server Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="server">
            <img src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/3eMPIDjl49YlAuYjS-x42t4ZvBwDJZhq84zKoHNAVls/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/347724952100667394/a_a76024fba4dbe97464128190a5b8cc91.gif?width=300&height=300"
                alt="">
            <span>Server Name</span>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="channel__list">

    </div>

    <div class="user__container">
        <div class="profile">
            <img src="https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/3eMPIDjl49YlAuYjS-x42t4ZvBwDJZhq84zKoHNAVls/%3Fsize%3D1024/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/347724952100667394/a_a76024fba4dbe97464128190a5b8cc91.gif?width=300&height=300"
                alt="">
            <div class="user">
                <div class="user__name">
                    WiperR
                </div>
                <div class="user__discrim">
                    #3131
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id="logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./static/js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but if you want to allow overflow as well as hide the scrollbar, you can use:-

```
#my-element::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}
```

and

```
#my-element {overflow: scroll;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css :

```
.server__list {
    overflow-x: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: remove overflow-x: visible; from .server__list selector